# "Oh for cute" - grammatical interpretation?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, slang, colloquialisms

So I'm from Minnesota, and while most of our English is fine, we're known for a few -- shall we call them -- *adaptations*.  One of these is the phrase "oh for <*insert adjective here*>".

It's used as an exclamation if I have my terminology down (which I might not).  For example, maybe I pull out my scarf (it's Minnesota, remember).  My grandma thinks it's a cute scarf, so she says, "oh for cute!"

Obviously it's a compliment (in this case), and the meaning is clear enough, but I'm wondering if (1) it's grammatically correct, and (if not), if there's a way to stretch the English language to make it not quite correct maybe, but almost fit in.

Comment: It’s obvious grammatical in Minnesota. I’ve never heard it before, and it wouldn’t be grammatical for me (but I’m not from Minnesota), but it’s easily understandable. The only parallel I can think of that exists in my English is “for shame”, which much more uncontroversially uses a noun.

Comment: Oh nice.  That's the sort of thing I'm looking for - you could make that an answer

Comment: I'd never heard the expression "Oh, for cute!" before I moved to Minnesota and became engaged to a Fargo girl (who has since, for 42 years, been my wife).  She did not use the expression, but her neighbor friend used it regularly.  It is easily understood, even to an "outsider" such as I was, so I don't think it needs much rigorous analysis.

Comment: I think  Janus Bahs Jacquet has the measure of it with an inversion of, "Oh for shame". There's also "Oh for Heaven's sake", "Oh for a cool drink", "Oh for the wings of a dove", and so on. They all have different origins but "Oh for cute" is immediately understandable to me as an English person even though this is the first time I've ever come across it.

Comment: Related - [Are you for sure about that?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/07/for-sure.html)

Comment: I'll note that I've occasionally heard "Oh, for cool!"  It's probably a hair more common than "Oh, for cute!"  (Well, maybe not!)

Comment: Apparently saying "Oh, for cute!" is a part of [speaking Minnesotan](http://www.citypages.com/news/20-things-you-say-that-make-you-a-minnesotan-6571633).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It sounds as though it's pretty much  equivalent to the "There's {adjective}!" expression ascribed (I'm not too sure how justifiably) to Welsh speakers.

Comment: I've found citations for a paper: Graham, J. (2006). 'Oh For' as a Scandinavian-influenced Linguistic Feature of Minnesota and Utah. (2006). Paper presented at the 60th Annual RMMLA Convention, Tucson, AZ, October 12-14. I can't find the text though.

Answer (score 3):

I've lived in Minnesota for over 30 years. Here is my theory about "Oh for cute" (although I have scant evidence to back it up). Years ago, I often heard the phase "Oh for cute" with a pause between between the words "for" and "cute," as if the person were saying "Oh, for ... cute!" I believe the missing words are "... goodness sake, that's ...." The speaker at first intends to say "Oh, for goodness sake, that's cute!" But after getting the "Oh, for" out, they are overcome with emotion and cut straight to the adjective, "cute." Over time "Oh, for goodness sake that's cute!" morphed to "Oh, for ... cute!" and morphed again into "Oh for cute!"

Answer (score 3):

An educated guess:

"For" exists in both English and Norwegian - identical spelling and pronunciation, mostly. Obviously it's used as a preposition in English, but in Norwegian, it means "too" as in, "too much" or "too expensive".  So, maybe this odd little habit of saying things like "for cute" or "for fun" is based on the original Norwegian "for" and not the English preposition "for"?

Comment: Generally, we prefer answers that are less than 100% speculation, with the ideal amount being 0%.

Comment: Given that Norwegian at one time saturated "Minnesotan", assuming a Norwegian influence is not at all out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Most universal equivalent I know is "Oh for sure" https://tenor.com/search/oh-for-sure-gifs

Used to be an affirmation but now a term that kids use sarcastically when  talking   https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Oh%20for%20sure

Answer (score 1):

Having lived in Minnesota now for 5 years, I can say definitively that the word "for" is used in place of the correct word, "how."

Using your example, "Oh, **for** cute!" ought to be grammatically said, "Oh, **how** cute!"

Another example would be "Oh, **for** fun." instead should be "Oh, **how** fun."

Comment: How do you prove that it’s ***how*** and not “***now that’s***” or Matt’s “***goodness sake, that’s***” that should be substituted?

Comment: I like this answer actually.  It's another word that effectively means the same thing as Matt's answer, but it still works well.

Comment: @Cullub - While this answer does give a reasonable way of interpreting what's meant.  It by no means is ***definitive*** in its assertion that this is the "correct" word.

Answer (score 0):

For = too in Norwegian. That is where this use of "for" comes from in Minnesotan dialect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Riley, welcome to ELU. Please provide sources for your claims, and read through existing answers before posting your own, as this has already been mentioned in larger detail.